# How to collect multiple columns when using has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

In this page http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association, I want to do `Physician.first.appointments` or `Physician.first.patients` that returns ​**appointments.appointment_date** AND **patients.name**​ in the same data structure and return type is **ActiveRecord::Relation**, since I want to chain more methods after it.

My question is: how do I do this? I can write a scope with `joins` and `where`, but that wouldn't satisfy my requirements stated above. Do I need to override some method? Am I in a rabbit hole?

Comment: try using `Model.eager_load(:my_has_many_association)`. Also nothing prevents you from creating a new activeRelation from a previous activeRelation by adding `where` or other statements. I'm afraid your question is a little to broad for an answer as is. Maybe give us some code we can help you on

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, now fixed. I wanted to make `Physician.first.appointments` to give me the default, plus additional information from the join table. This is my real puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment here's a basic example of what you can do with `ActiveRecord` :

```
class Doctor
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient
  #...
end

@doctor = Doctor.includes(:appointments).first

@doctor.name #=> Dr Howdoyoudo
@doctor.appointments.each {|ap| puts ap.expected_at }
# OR
@doctor.appointments.map {|app| app.expected_at } 
#=> [Wed, 04 Mar 2015 09:23:37 CET +01:00, Wed, 04 Mar 2015 09:23:37 CET +03:00]
```

**Update** : if you need patients as well you must specify it in the `includes` (only to avoid the O(n) query) :

```
 @doctor = Doctor.includes(appointments: :patient).first
 @doctor.appointments.map do |app| 
   "#{app.patient.name} is expected at #{app.expected_at}"
 end
```

`ActiveRelation` can be reused here :

```
Doctor.includes(appointments: :patient).class #=> ActiveRelation
Doctor.includes(appointments: :patient).appointments.class #=> ActiveRelation
```

This is only a start ! I suggest you try out as much as you can and come back with another question when you hit a wall. Good luck !

Comment: But I want to have `patients.name​` and I want return type as ActiveRecord::Relation, each/map will give me an array

Comment: Yes this answers most of my puzzles. Thanks a lot. I was trying to put include / joins in the wrong places.